# Sed command to replace a word in a tab and space-separated line of text

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I have the below fields separated by tabs and spaces in file "text.txt". I want to use sed command to find "^@\t*\s*text1\t*\s*text2\t*\s*100" and replace it with "^@\t*\s*text1\t*\s*text2\t*\s*1000"

```
<Field1>     <Field2>       <Field3>    <Field4>
@             text1         text2        100
$             text3         text4        200
```

I have tried using the below sed command:

```
sed -i "/^\s*\@\s+text1\s+text2\s*/c\@/\t/\ttext1/\ttext2/\t/\t1000" /text.txt
```

However, nothing is getting replaced in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are using unescaped `+` in the POSIX BRE regex that is treated as a literal `+` symbol.

You need to use `-E` option to enable POSIX ERE syntax, where `+` is treated as a quantifier. Besides, you have several redundant `/` chars in the replacement, you need to remove them.

You can use

```sh
sed -E -i "/^\s*\@\s+text1\s+text2\s*/c\@\t\ttext1\ttext2\t1000" file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/M7AkXf).